# Using Multiple libraries for a single ViewController/UIcollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

first of all sorry for that Question Title you can just read on to know my problem. I am a bit confused about adding multiple libraries that points to a single view controller. So the situation is I have  a ViewController where I need  a SideMenu and a Drag and Drop Functionality. The ViewController have UICollectionView with Images in it that can be used to drag and Drop in between the images itself and Need  a SideMenu that the user can Swipe to navigate to find Menu Items. For SideMenu I have Tried this library [SSASideMenu](https://github.com/SSA111/SSASideMenu)
 and for Drag and Drop I used [DragDropCollectionView](https://github.com/LiorNn/DragDropCollectionView)
when I use one library at a time I can make it work but when i use both I get this error at this line

[image]

to use SSASidemenu we need some code in AppDelegate File

```
 window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

      //  MARK : Setup SSASideMenu

        let sideMenu = SSASideMenu(contentViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController()), leftMenuViewController: LeftMenuViewController(), rightMenuViewController: RightMenuViewController())
        sideMenu.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "Background.jpg")
        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.MenuViewEffect(fade: true, scale: true, scaleBackground: false))
        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.ContentViewEffect(alpha: 1.0, scale: 0.7))
        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.ContentViewShadow(enabled: true, color: UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.6, radius: 6.0))
        sideMenu.delegate = self

        window?.rootViewController = sideMenu
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

inside **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

but when I comment this code in appdelegate the Dragdrop works great.

So my question Is, is it possible to add multiple libraries in a single ViewController ? if so what's going wrong with my method? Can I achieve both the functionality in a same viewcontroller ?
Created a Sample Project with both The Libraries Mentioned in my question. Can get it [HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1TZvXTORPO8b1g0NE4wb05HNE0)

Comment the line in  Appdelegate and The DragandDropCollectionview works fine and if not error occurs

Comment: You can create small demo project with above libraries and code, so anyone can download , work on it and give you a solution.

Comment: @Hasya but where Can I upload it ? I will create a new project with those libraries...

Comment: You can use your google drive cloud or Gist (github) or pastebin..

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [**DragDropCollectionView** example](https://github.com/LiorNn/DragDropCollectionView/blob/master/Sample%20Project/DragDrop/ViewController.swift) , you must configure your class where you have **viewDidLoad** (like your picture as showed), otherwise you cannot set delegate:

```
class ViewController: ...(your class type), DrapDropCollectionViewDelegate {
}
```

Comment: Didi you mean like this  `class ViewController : UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource, DrapDropCollectionViewDelegate`   ?

Comment: I already have it in my code. I took a copy of the code from my project  :)

Comment: That's the better thing

Comment: any other guess on the matter ?

Comment: creating a new project... :) let you know when I finish. Will make it fast.